# Full page White background preloader fade in on link click (example)

Tags: html, css, web, preloader

i was curious on how to do that to apply this on my webpage, if you can see this website :http://www.dynamicworks.eu/ and click on any link at the top, you will notice a smooth fade in white background is appeared. If anyone can tell me how to do it i would be very glad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow Below code snippet to make it work. Please feel free to ask your queries.

```js
$('.faded-div').fadeOut(2000);
$('a.fade-in').click(function(){
    $('.faded-div').fadeIn(2000);
});
$('a.fade-out').click(function(){
    $('.faded-div').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

```css
.faded-div{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:blue ; 
    display: none;
}
.faded-div a
{
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faded-div"><a href="#" class="fade-out">Click To FadeOut</a></div>
  <a href="#" class="fade-in">Click To FadeIn</a>
```

Comment: now i need to apply it for wordpress zerif-lite theme

Comment: you just need to add this css and jquery to style your theme and use respective classes in your theme's view page like we have used for this demo.

Answer (score 0):

Creating html overlay

```
<body>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  .....
</body>
```

CSS styling

```
.overlay{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff; 
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('a.do-fade').click(function(){
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(200);
}
```

You can do more stuff to be smooth

Removing display none from the css style and apply some javascript on window load or document ready

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.overlay').fadeOut(200);
})
```

Comment: nothing happens can you be more specific? i want to to it on links like the website

Comment: Have you installed jquery ? Add this in the header, or above your script
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

html e.g.:

```
<div class="blank-div"></div> // somewhere in the <body>

<div class="some-link"> // your link
    <a class="my-link" href="/your/path.html">Click me</a>
</div>
```

js ( using jquery):

```
$(".my-link").click(function(){
    $(".blank-div").fadeIn("slow", function(){
        location.href="/your/path.html";
    });
});
```

css:

```
.blank-div{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

you can also modify this code with some more animation or styles